# Unable to request html content with AJAX localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to embed HTML code into a `div` element with Ajax. (likewise we do with an iframe). I am testing this on localhost firstly, to avoid Same Origin Policy issues.

The web app is running on a wamp server.

There are 2 files:

1. Script with Ajax request (index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>

 <div id="testajax" style="width: 500px;height: 300px;border: 1px solid red;top:120px;
position:relative;">

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/site.php',
    dataType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(response) {
            $('#testajax').html(response);
    }
 });
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

2. File with html code I intend to retrieve (site.php):

```php
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div id="header">This is a header</div>
 <div id="main">
 <div id="content">This is my main content.</div>
 <div id="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">This is my footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There aren't any log or network errors on the browser... so I don't see what is wrong in this scenario. Why the Ajax success is never executed?

Comment: try echo without HTML, Body and Head tag

Comment: Honestly, before trying to output it with php, I did it with plain html text. But It doesn't work either way. Only used php to add headers and try it to work.

Comment: Go use your browser dev tools, network panel, to see how exactly the request is answered.

Comment: The browser or jQuery may not like the extra doctype, html, head, body tags. Try just serving the content inside the body tag. then add a console.log(response); to your success ... see what your getting?

Comment: Just a heads up and if your using jQuery 3 this might be your issue: [Deprecation Notice](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: It is solved. Thank you, I just was not loading the proper jQuery like I have shown in my example... on the html head.. I don't understand why I had no error logs . I would love to delete the question but I am unable :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a long time testing this because I had no errors on the developer console or network profiler.

As the real code is very large, I made a snippet to make the question, and this snippet actually has not any errors.

So my real code has not any jQuery included on the file I was using the Ajax function. It was actually injected on the `<head>` element within other PHP file.

Also I was not getting error on logs because I had FireBug addon, and it is currently Legacy :), and doesn't work well.

Ref: [FireFox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-add-technology-modernizing).

Comment: learned something new `<head>` how to print HTML in stackoverflow :
)

Comment: This is a very useful guide for [SO markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) :)

Comment: Ya but I am kind of going @ it as I need it ... API's are cheating :O

Answer (score 1):

What about simplifying things?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#testajax').load('http://localhost/site.php', function() {
          alert('Load was performed.');
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see your code has sense. I really have experience with ajax requests, but this didn't work neither, for some reason.

Comment: No errors in console? This is quite straight-forward, so I'd rather check the originating page output...

Comment: In the end, my `.ajax()` call didn't work, but your method `.load()` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up your using jQuery 3 this might be your issue

[Deprecation Notice](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

If that doesn't work I would:

1. Remove extra doctype, html, head, body tags (as browser or jQuery may not like the).
2. Then add a console.log(response); to your success/done function

Comment: :) I had not really the full `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

String, I just made a short working snippet to do the question. But the actual code missed the full jQuery import.

Comment: @Roizpi You know there is a badge for answering your own question :P

Answer (score 0):

You should echo html. your php file is not sending anything to client.

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

echo '<div id="header">This is a header</div><div id="main"><div id="content">This is my main content.</div><div id="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div></div><div id="footer">This is my footer</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Nonsense ... anything _outside_ the `<?php ...?>` tags is normal output that gets send anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach didn't work neither.

Comment: @Roizpi Please check your devtools.  check network requests.

Comment: Echoing HTML is a bad practice as you lose all intellisense, you lose formatting, and you have to mix or escape quotes.